# Reverse video playback in OpenCV

Tags: video, opencv, reverse

Is it possible to play videos backwards in OpenCV?
Either by an API call or by buffering video frames and reversing the order into
a new video file.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only practical way to do it is to manually extract frames, buffer them ( on memory or files) then reload them in reverse order.

The problem is that video compressors are all exploiting time redundancy - the fact that two consecutive frames are most of the time very similar. So, they encode a full frame from time to time (usually every few hundred frames) then only send differences between the previous and current.

Now, for decoding to work, it must be done in the same order - decode a keyframe (a full one), then for each new frame, add differences to obtain the current image.

This strategy makes it very hard to reverse play in video. There are several techniques, but all involve buffering.

Now, you may have seen the CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES parameters, described by Astor. It seems ok, but because of the issues described above, OpenCV is not able to correctly jump to a specific frame (there are multiple bugs open on these issues). They (OpenCV devs) are working on some solutions, but even those will be very slow (they involve going back to previous keyframe, then decoding back to the selected one). If you use this technique, each frame must be decoded hundreds of times on average, making it very slow. And yet, it doesn't work.

**Edit**
If you pursue the buffer way to reverse it, keep in mind that a decoded video will quickly eat off the memory resources of a regular computer. A usual 720p video **one minute long** needs **4.7GB** of memory when decompressed! Storing frames as individual files on disk is a practical solution to this problem.

Comment: :) not yey, although I am thinking of some patches. But I've had some problems with VideoCapture syncronization, and I discovered some of its flaws.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, similar to [ArtemStorozhuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260499/1831052) is to use the FPS to move from the frame domain into the time domain, then seek backwards using `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` (which doesn't hammer the CPU like `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` can). Here's my sample code, which works perfectly on an .mpg, using only about 50% CPU.

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cv::VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);

  double frame_rate = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

  // Calculate number of msec per frame.
  // (msec/sec / frames/sec = msec/frame)
  double frame_msec = 1000 / frame_rate;

  // Seek to the end of the video.
  cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 1);

  // Get video length (because we're at the end).
  double video_time = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);

  cv::Mat frame;
  cv::namedWindow("window");

  while (video_time > 0)
  {
    // Decrease video time by number of msec in one frame
    // and seek to the new time.
    video_time -= frame_msec;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, video_time);

    // Grab the frame and display it.
    cap >> frame;
    cv::imshow("window", frame);

    // Necessary for opencv's event loop to work.
    // Wait for the length of one frame before
    // continuing the loop. Exit if the user presses
    // any key. If you want the video to play faster
    // or slower, adjust the parameter accordingly.    
    if (cv::waitKey(frame_msec) >= 0)
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: so.. seeking by msec is less cpu consuming that seeking by frame? why? because of compression?

Comment: I think it has to do with the way videos are encoded... there's a timestamp in every packet, indicating the time since the start of the video, so seeking to a particular time within the video is a simple binary search operation. But I'm not an expert on video encodings, so take this comment with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. See code with comments:

```
//create videocapture
VideoCapture cap("video.avi");

//seek to the end of file
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 1);

//count frames
int number_of_frames = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

//create Mat frame and window to display
Mat frame;
namedWindow("window");

//main loop
while (number_of_frames > 0)
{
    //decrease frames and move to needed frame in file
    number_of_frames--;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, number_of_frames);

    //grab frame and display it
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("window", frame);

    //wait for displaying
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Also read [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) article.

Comment: cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, number_of_frames); really hammers CPU, but works.