# Playback loop option in OpenCV videos

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to build a **playback loop option for an OpenCV video**. My program uses Python multiprocessing, and has a button send `loopswitch` calls through `queue4` to enable or disable the loop option. My specific problem is that my video freezes on the last frame, and **I would like to know if the line `vidFile.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1)` is a correct use of the `cv2.VideoCapture.set()` method**, and should indeed take the video back to frame 1 and replay it (as I think it should).

### EDIT

After revising my code, it now triggers a runtime C++ error, but no other precisions are given.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260842/2322456), it would seem that using `cv2.VideoCapture.set()` to jump between frame is buggy. Has anyone managed it anyway?

Thank you,

My code for the capture process (`queue`and `queue2` are in and out queues):

```
def image_capture(queue, con, queue2, queue4):
    videopath = con.recv()
    vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)
    fps = vidFile.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
    waitframe = 1/fps
    con.send(waitframe)#sending waitkey duration through pipe to update_image()
    loopswitch = False #init for playing video in a loop 
    while True:
        if queue4.empty():
           pass
        else:
           queueval = queue4.get()
            if queueval=='loop':
               if loopswitch==False:
                  loopswitch = True
               elif loopswitch==True:
                  loopswitch = False
        try:
            flag, frame=vidFile.read()
            if flag==0:
               if loopswitch==False:
                  queue2.put(None)
                  break
               elif loopswitch==True:
                  vidFile.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1)
                  continue
            else:                
               queue2.put(frame)
               cv2.waitKey(waitframe)
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I partially solved it by replacing vidFile.set `(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1)` by `vidFile.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0)`, although this works for .avi files only.

Answer (score 14):

For python3, opencv3.1.0, raspberry pi 3

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('intro.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    #cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    #cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    else:
       print('no video')
       cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
       continue
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: For me, it made sense to add `continue` after cap.set() so that the loop restarted and the rest of my code that worked on the frame wouldn't run yet. Just a heads up for anyone who tries this and doesn't immediately get it.

Answer (score 4):

I can get looped video playback by using an if statement for when the frame count reaches `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` and then resetting the frame count and `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, num)` to the same value. The below example keeps looping the video for me.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video') 
frame_counter = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_counter += 1
    #If the last frame is reached, reset the capture and the frame_counter
    if frame_counter == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
        frame_counter = 0 #Or whatever as long as it is the same as next line
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It also works to recapture the video instead of resetting the frame count:

```
if frame_counter == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
    frame_counter = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
```

So at least it works for me to use `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, num)` to loop a video. What happens if you reset to the zeroth frame instead of the first (like with the avi method)?

Comment: A comment from another user with insufficient rep to type it here: _I'm using cv2 (v.3.0.0) and found that frame_counter was never == to cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT): as the cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT is a double, but the counter is not_. I have not had time to test his suggestion yet.

Comment: the line      frame_counter == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) needs to be  
      frame_counter == cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)-1:

Answer (score 1):

```
self.cap =cv2.VideoCapture(self.filename)       
while True:

    ret,frameset = self.cap.read()
             
    if self.cap.get(1)>self.cap.get(7)-2:#video loop
        self.cap.set(1,0)#if frame count > than total frame number, next frame will be zero
    cv2.imshow("G",frameset)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
self.cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Capture will be re started always when the frame count matches total frame number - 2(I use -2 to keep the while True)

Answer (score 0):

For the C++ guys:

```
void openVideo() {
    cap.open(videoName);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Video file not loaded!" << std::endl;
    }

    numberOfFrames = (int)cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    std::cout << "Start grabbing" << std::endl
        << "Press any key to terminate" << std::endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);
        frameCounter++;
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frameCounter == numberOfFrames) {
            frameCounter = 0;
            cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
        }
        if (frame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        cv::imshow("Live", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(5) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
}
```